# CSS3 Animation transition

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

The problem is I can't figure out how to disable kind of scrolling effect to make each picture occupy whole space of box. To create kind of gif image, using only sprit-sheet and CSS.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Hyg3C/4420/)

```
 <title>Hey</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="learn.css">
    <body>
      <div class="animation"></div>
    </body>

.animation {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  background: url('http://s16.postimg.org/8f5770kpx/sprite.png') center;
  animatio-play-state: paused;
  animation: play 5s steps(10) infinite;
  transorm: translateZ(0);
}

@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: 100px; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
.animation {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  background: url('http://s16.postimg.org/8f5770kpx/sprite.png');
  background-position:0px 0px;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation: play 5s steps(10) infinite;
  transorm: translateZ(0);
}

@keyframes play {
     from { background-position:0px 0px; }
  to   { background-position:1280px 0px; }
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Hyg3C/4421/

So, from-to are actually 'steps', we move background position in 10 steps. If you remove steps parameter from animation - you can get nice infinite scrolling,  btw, but this provides 'gif-like' behavior...

Comment: Thank you, nevermind. That helped me to resolve a problem and keep back on learning. Have a nice day ;)

Comment: No, problem, glad to help! :)